# Show or hide SPFx extension based on user permissions

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, modern-experience, spfx-extensions, pnp-js-core

I like to show or hide extension as per user permission in SPFx ,suppose if user present in SP-group extension is visible or hide it

```
 @override
  public onListViewUpdated(event: IListViewCommandSetListViewUpdatedParameters): void {
    var Libraryurl = this.context.pageContext.list.title; 
   
    
    const compareTwoCommand: Command = this.tryGetCommand('COMMAND_2');
    if (compareTwoCommand) {
      // This command should be hidden unless exactly one row is selected.
      const listname:string =this.context.pageContext.list.title
      const Librarylistname:string ="Documents"
      
      compareTwoCommand.visible =(event.selectedRows.length > 0 && Libraryurl == "Documents" )
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by writing your business logic to check the user permissions based on SharePoint group membership (or list permissions) in **`onListViewUpdated`** method and show/hide the list view command.

All you need to do is set the `visible` property of your command to `true/false` based on user permissions.

```
const compareTwoCommand: Command = this.tryGetCommand('COMMAND_2');

if (compareTwoCommand) {
    //write business logic to check user permissions here
    compareTwoCommand.visible = true; //show command

    //compareTwoCommand.visible = hide; //Hide command
}
```

**References**:

1. [Show and hide commands based on users its permissions](https://www.eliostruyf.com/showing-or-hiding-sharepoint-framework-listview-custom-actions-based-on-permissions-and-selected-items/)
2. [Showing a ListView CommandSet if a user is in a SharePoint Group](https://wutek.co.uk/showing-a-listview-commandset-if-a-user-is-in-a-sharepoint-group/)